# Fail to load any of the projects in a solution

Tags: visual-studio-2012, .net-framework-version

Yesterday I opened the solution and everything was OK. Today I tried opening it and I'm getting the same error for all the projects:

> error  : Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Internal.Tasks.Dataflow, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The file
>   or directory is corrupted and unreadable. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80070570)

I reinstalled visual studio (ultimate 2012). I tried to reinstall .NET framework 4 but windows 8 won't let me. I verified that on another machine the solution works fine. I deleted everythin and took a fresh copy from the source control - a copy which works on a differrent machine - with the same results.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Why won't windows 8 let you reinstall .NET framework? Sounds like the problem to me.

Comment: It's not in the add/remove list

Comment: Then just try installing it from scratch, i.e. without uninstalling first.

Comment: The installer won't run since it detects it's already installed. Even if I rename the folder it still won't run.